# What is the purpose of a field width of 1 in a call to Pascal's "write" procedure?

Tags: io, formatting, pascal

I have noticed several instances in Donald Knuth's Pascal programs of code that is effectively like the following:

```pascal
write(n:1);
```

For example, here is a paraphrase (so that you need not read the whole program) of section 166 of [TANGLE](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/web/tangle.pdf); the `error` procedure deals with reporting the location of an error. This code is part of a parsing routine. The type of `parenthesis_balance` is a subrange of the integers.

```pascal
if parenthesis_balance > 0 then
  begin if parenthesis_balance = 1 then writeln('! Missing )'); error
    else writeln('! Missing ', parenthesis_balance:1, ' )''s');
    while parenthesis_balance > 0 do
      begin insert_character(')'); parenthesis_balance := parenthesis_balance - 1;
      end;
  end;
```

Many more cases are found in section 1334 of [TeX](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf).

What is the point of `write(n:1)`? It seems unnecessary. Usually, in situations where you can specify the minimum number of characters output by a printing routine, the only time you need to give an explicit width of 1 is when it's possible that no characters might be output. For example, in C `printf("%s", s);` will print nothing if `s` is `""`; `printf("%1s", s);` will always print at least one character. But Knuth is printing integers, so there is always at least one character to output (a single digit for integers in the range `0..9`).

---

I have one hypothesis. In the original Pascal report, the description of `write` contains the following:

> The [arguments to the `write` procedure] have the following forms:
>
> > `e:m` `e:m:n` `e`
>
> `e` represents the value to be "written" on the [specified file], and `m`
> and `n` are so-celled field width parameters. If the value `e`,
> which is either a number, a character, a Boolean value, or a
> string requires less than `m` characters for its
> representation, then an adequate number of blanks is issued
> such that exactly `m` characters are written. If `m` is omitted,
> an implementation-defined default value will be assumed.

(And much the same is said by the [ISO 7185 specification](https://www.pascal-central.com/docs/iso7185.pdf).)
In my experience, when it comes to field widths in formatted output, specifications generally specify that padding characters are printed only if a minimum width is provided. See for example the [ANSI Common Lisp standard, section 22.3.4.1](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/22_cda.htm), the [C2x draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2346.pdf), clause 7.21.6.1. But the Pascal description implies that an implementation could set the default minimum at, say, 5, in which case output from the Knuth excerpt above could look like

> `! Missing     2 )'s`

had the width been left unspecified. Then a value of 1 becomes completely defensible.

Comment: I believe your hypothesis is correct, n:1 ensures that the compiler does not use a default field width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it simply ensures there are no leading spaces. The [ISO standard 7185 says](http://www.pascal-central.com/iso7185.html#6.9.3.1%20Write-parameters):

> `Write(f, e)` shall be equivalent to the form `write(f, e:TotalWidth)`, using a default value for `TotalWidth` that depends on the type of `e`; for *integer-type*, *real-type*, and *Boolean-type*, the default values shall be implementation-defined.

Some Pascal compilers had and have an “implementation-defined” default value for `TotalWidth` on *integer-type* `write`-parameters of, for instance, `20`, which simply isn’t nice for that kind of output in your TANGLE source code fragment, you see?

The procedures `write`/`writeLn` on `text` files are primarily intended and designed to produce human-readable, *legible* output. If you are printing like *several* number values line after line, you *do* want them to be *aligned to the right*. For this use case, it’s great that you do not need to extra specify `:20` (or the name of a constant) *every time*, you know.

Note that in Extended Pascal, ISO 10206, which introduces the data type `string`, the `TotalWidth` format specifier for *write-parameters* of type `char` or `string` denotes *the* *exact* *width*, i. e. this may *clip* the output (or pad it with spaces like usual). For example `write('Foobar':0)` will (in EP) print *nothing*. This is different to an equivalent `printf`.